# Sub query to eliminate duplicates in the result set

Tags: t-sql

```
select 
         PIH.[No_] as [Document No]
        ,PIH.[Pre-Assigned No_] as [Original No]
        ,PIL. [Description]
        ,(PL.[Outstanding Quantity]*PL.[Direct Unit Cost]) as Dispute_Amt
        ,100*(COALESCE(PL.[Outstanding Quantity]*PL.[Direct Unit Cost] / NULLIF(PL.[Amount],0), 0) ) as [Dispute%]
        ,PIH.[Buy-from Vendor Name] 
        ,PIH.[Buy-from Vendor No_]  
        ,PH."Creation Date"
        ,PH."Expected Receipt Date" as [Actl.Posting Date]
        ,PH."Document Date" 
        ,PIH.[Notes] as [Header Notes]
        ,(PL.[Outstanding Quantity] *PL.[Direct Unit Cost]) as [Tolerance Amount]
        ,100*(COALESCE(PL.[Outstanding Quantity]*PL.[Direct Unit Cost] / NULLIF(PL.[Amount],0), 0) ) as [Tolerance%] 
        ,PL.[Document No_] as [P.O.Number]
        ,PL.[Original Quantity]  as [PO.Quantity]
        ,PL.[Amount] as [PO Value]
        ,PL.[Quantity Received] as [Delivered Qty]
        ,PL.[Quantity Invoiced] as [Invoiced Qty]
        ,PL.[Return Qty_ to Ship] as [Return Qty]    
        ,PL.[Outstanding Quantity]
        ,PL.[Direct Unit Cost]        
                 from [ Trading$Purch_ Inv_ Header] PIH
        Inner join [Trading$Purch_ Inv_ Line] PIL
        ON PIH.[No_]=PIL.[Document No_]
        inner join [Trading$Purchase Header] PH
        ON PH.[No_]=PIH.[PO Number]
        inner join [Trading$Purchase Line] PL 
        On PL.[Document No_]=PH.[No_]
        where 
        PIL.[No_]  in ('170050','700220','700300')
```

[If am using this code iam getting 4500 records ,but i want to filter the result set by eliminating duplicate PIH[Document_No] with PIL[No_]'s 170050,700220,700300 with invoice issues like missing stock,Invoice dispute amount etc  i.e no records with dispute amt zero should come up.

any help please?
    ]

Comment: You can make use of the keyword `DISTINCT` and also for the dispute amount records with zero. You can add in an another clause after the `WHERE` similar to `AND Dispute_Amt <> 0`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, actually i am trying to report purchase order discrepancies and i need to check the discrepancy against items , the query i am using is not giving the correct PO discrepancy of all the related items. iam using pur_inv_line,Pur_Line,Pur_Inv_Header and Pur_Header tables for the result set, any ideas please

Answer (score 0):

WHERE PL.[Outstanding Quantity]*PL.[Direct Unit Cost] is not null 
and PL.[Outstanding Quantity]*PL.[Direct Unit Cost] <> 0

Comment: Thank you for the reply, actually i am trying to report purchase order discrepancies and i need to check the discrepancy against items , the query i am using is not giving the correct PO discrepancy of all the related items. iam using pur_inv_line,Pur_Line,Pur_Inv_Header and Pur_Header tables for the result set, any ideas please